# Socket.io with Express, how does express app know what port to listen on?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am pretty new to nodejs and very new to socket.io and express. I have some code that is working, but am having trouble understanding exactly why it's working.

My question for the below code is how does the express app know to listen on port 80? There's a server.listen. But there is no app.listen in the code. Yet app.post() readily accepts posted data.

Please consider the following code

```
var https = require('https');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//var io = require('socket.io');
var zlib = require('zlib');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('my.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('my.crt')
};


var serverPort = 80;
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


// log when the server is ready
server.listen(serverPort, function() {
    console.log('Web socket server up and running at port %s', serverPort);
    // this prints 80, as expected
});


app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
    // working code is in here that receives the post variables and responds
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Express, the `app` object is just a request handler for some http server.  If you call `app.listen()`, then the `app` object will create an http server for you. But, if you have created your own http server (which your code example does), then the `app` object just becomes a request listener on that server with this line of your code:

```
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
```

That creates the http server and registers `app` as a request listener (so it sees all incoming requests).  This allows the Express app object to then process the routes that are registered with it to server routes like `app.get(...)` or `app.post(...)`.

And, the port for Express is the port for the http server so it's the port that was used when the http server was created.  What's important to understand here is that Express is not its own server.  It's just a request listener for some http server.

In your code example, your http server is set up for port 80 so that's the port being used and Express gets registered as a request handler on all those incoming http requests on that port.

---

If you look at the [source code for `app.listen()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L615), you see this:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

All, it does is create an http server with the `app` object as a listener and then call `.listen()` on that new server.

Comment: Thanks! That really clears it up. So frustrating when something works and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

the app does not have to know on which port to listen. Basically, `server` is your HTTP server binding which listens on port 80 in your example. `var server = https.createServer(options, app);` then tells the server to listen on port 80 for HTTP requests and forward them to your app. The app then does the routing stuff that links the function you sepcified with `app.post(...)` to a specific request URL (/api in this case).

TL;DR: The app does not need to listen, because the server is the only communication interface to the outside.